# how pass variable in os.path.exists and subprocess?

Tags: python, wxpython, subprocess, wxwidgets

i am doing GUI using python and wxpython. My one of panel has to download a file from ftp and then it has to execute but i cant hard-code file. so i used

```
    file = self.sc1.GetValue()
```

which is working as usual.

but when i check using os.path.exist() , i am not able to find it it shows Type error.

and i have to run that file i think i use subprocess ,i have to make this  happen by using variable "file"(i cant use actual file name which is downloaded)
 please help me to finish my project.

Comment: You cannot check if a particular file exists without specifying the file name or retrieve the file name and path from somewhere. The same applies to executing the file as well.

Comment: @Tuxdude so u are telling that no solution?i cant run or search a file using its variable name?

Comment: but the python script will be knowing that this variable name is "zzz" so it don't check "zzz" ? or it checks variable name?

Comment: Are you saying the variable `zzz` is a string that contains the file name ? If so, why don't you try to construct the full path name using this string ?

Comment: first, what is `sc1`? a spin control? - then, what `file` contains after you type something? may you log the content somewhere (a `print` statement is fine)- third: may you paste the "Type error" entirely? forth: may you paste more code (the definition of sc1, the part of code that rises error...)? for the info you provide it seems to me that you are using an integer as a filename

Comment: @Tuxdude: ZZZ = self.sc2.GetValue(); if os.path.exists("/biz/zzz") is valid or not?

Comment: the two lines are unrelated. `/biz/zzz` is just a string, it not refers to ZZZ variable. do you mean `if os.path.exists("/biz/%s"%ZZZ)`?

Comment: @furins:thanks a lot. and sorry for my description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the file using urllib2 or the cool requests library (see this fun [article](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/06/07/python-101-how-to-download-a-file/)). I would do this in a button event handler. When the download is finished, you'll know the path yourself since you told it where to put the file:

```
f = urllib2.urlopen(url)
data = f.read()
path = "path/to/file.txt"
with open(path, "wb") as textFile:
    textFile.write(data)
```

Then you can use os.path.exist(path) to check if the file actually got written to disk. If it exists, then you can pass it to subprocess.